# getting the latest version of plugin's in my parent pom.xml using versions-maven-plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have `versions-maven-plugin` in **pom.xml** (this POM is the parent POM which resides somewhere on network) and my project's pom.xml considers it as parent and download it locally when build for the first time.

Now I want to get the information on the latest versions of plugins which are used in parent pom.xml(one that resides on network) i type the following command at the root of my project as

```
mvn versions:display-plugin-updates
```

but this does not give the parent pom plugin's latest version;It gives me the latest versions available for the plugin i used in my project pom.xml.

So can anyone guide me know how can I find the latest version of all the plugins used in the pom.xml(that resides over the network and a downloaded copy is available locally).

Regards,
Rajesh

Comment: This question has not been asked before.If you read it completely you will find that it is different.

Answer (score 1):

I just got this working...I took the pom.xml(one copied locally from the network at location user/rajesh/.m2/repository/....) from the local repository and changed the name to pom.xml to some folder and run the

mvn versions:display-plugin-updates

and that worked for me.I could see all the version updates.

Rajesh